# Jasper Reports - create temporary table and use its data in select query

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I need to generate daily report using Jasper Reports. The problem is that for some days there might be no data. So my idea was to create a temporary table with all days from the period I'm asking about, select and join them with data from the other table.

But is it possible to do in one Jasper query?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You can write code (at any language of with help of RDBMS) for creation temporary table and after that use this table at report

Comment: For each subdataset in Jasper Report template, you can only write one single query - there is no way to write one query for creating the table and another one for selecting the data - so I'm looking for any reasonable solution / workaround.

Comment: IMHO, it is a bad idea to call a "non-select" query at report